# Long Label Buttons and Action

Tags: buttons

I have got some issue with Action button.

We have got 2 actions which you can do:

**- Move Applicant to the Next Stage**
or
**- Move Applicant to the [Name of Stage]**

Also each option can have additional action like "Send automated message" or "Create auto signature" etc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the same action can be performed with options, or without options, depending on an operator selection. Correct?

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko You are right

Comment: What about command links, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/ctrl-command-links and https://www.nngroup.com/articles/command-links/ ?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOiPRE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Or you group additional actions and offer one checkbox only.

Comment: Nice one mate !

Comment: I like it. However options can be selected (all or nothing)

Comment: I think mike’s suggestion to group actions and offer one checkbox is good for this case .